# Constant noise while recording with Zoom H1 through USB

Tags: usb, audio, pi-3b+, microphone, usb-audio

I'm trying to build up a recording station using a Raspberry pi 3B. I soldered four mics (two per channel) to a stereo jack and plugged it into the "external mic" audio input of the Zoom H1. Then I connected the Zoom H1 to the Raspberry using a USB cable, and here's the problem: I get a constant and annoying noise on both channels, but especially in the first one (left I guess?), or, in general, I don't get the same disturbance in both channels.
Here's an example:

[Audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQkqsfZZP0VUPGOPEBQUnjYgspW3ZUnY/view?usp=sharing)

Channel 1
[image: Channel 1]

Channel 2
[image: Channel 2]

Also, I don't know what's the strange "volume adjustement" (those dark bands that get wider) at the beginning of every recording (using arecord).

Here are a few things I can say about it:

- **There're no problems with the mics (they're properly connected).** If I
  don't connect the Zoom H1 to the Raspberry and I power everything
  with a battery I don't get any disturb.
- **Nothing's wrong with the Zoom H1.** I also tried with the Zoom H1n, and
  I got the same problem.
- **No power deficit.** With the Zoom H1n there's the option to power it
  with the battery, instead of taking the current from the USB cable.
  Even doing so, the problem still remains.
- **Raspberry is not defective.** I get the same problem also with another Raspberry pi 3B+.
- **The problem is not due to the recording program of Raspberry
  (arecord).** I can hear the noise also by listening in "monitoring
  mode", with putting the headphones' jack in the Zoom H1's audio
  output and listening what comes in.
- **The use of internal mics avoids it.** If I record with the built-in mics
  of the Zoom H1 I get rid of the noise.
- **Connecting the Zoom H1 to my laptop also avoids it.** If I connect the
  Zoom H1 by USB to my laptop I get rid of the noise.

That said, I don't know whether this is a Raspberry's or a Zoom H1's configuration problem...

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Do you get the noise when connecting the Zoom H1 to the laptop AND have the raspberry pi running near the external Zoom H1 mics? If so a shielded metal case for the Raspberry pi might help.

Comment: The mics are always at the same distance quite far apart, there shouldn't be interference from the Raspberry pi. If I take the the Zoom H1 closer to the Raspberry while connected to the laptop, I can't hear any difference...

Comment: I connected the ground from the AC power plug to the microphone ground and I got rid of the noise.

Comment: I moved the USB connector from adapter to RPI USB port. The 50Hz sound disappeared. This works for 5V powered audio. Some countries use 60Hz power supply.

Comment: @DanFroberg I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I get what you mean... What do you mean with "adapter"? Here in Switzerland the power supply should be 50Hz, so I don't know if that could be a problem... Thanks!
As I wrote months ago, I've been able to get rid of the main disturbing noise, but I still feel like the audio is not 100% clear, so I'm still trying to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @plaf2000, here in Sweden the adapter = power supply. I think the ground should be taken from the same point to reduce noise. I think it was happen when I moved USB from its adapter directly to USB of RPI. Noise totally disappeared. It was 5V loud speakers only.